# the issue could jeopardise the tour’s future

Tags: word-meaning

> The WTA released a strong statement on Sunday, with Simon calling for an investigation into Peng’s allegations, while he told the New York Times **the issue could jeopardise the tour’s future** in China despite the huge sums of money at stake.
> Source: [BT Sport](https://www.bt.com/sport/news/2021/november/wta-chairman-steve-simon-concerned-over-welfare-of-chinese-player-peng-shuai)

Does "the tour" refer to "BT Sport (a BT Sport's team performs around the world including China)"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the cited text contains the *only* instance of the queried word "tour" in the entire article, so I think this isn't even a question about the *use* of English, let alone *learning* English. It's about domain-specific knowledge in the world of professional tennis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BT_Group), formerly known as "British Telecom", is a British telecommunications company. Like many of its kind, BT offers news and other articles on their website, for example [sports news](https://www.bt.com/sport/news). So, the publisher of the news article is the sports section of the BT website, "BT Sport".

The [WTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_Tennis_Association) is "the principal organizing body of women's professional tennis." It organizes the [WTA Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Tour), which is a world-wide tour of tennis tournaments for women.

The WTA has released a statement calling for investigations into recent allegations. The article on BT Sport reports that Steven Simon, the WTA chairman, told the New York Times (another news publisher) that he's worried about how the Chinese might react to that statement. Mr. Simon is, according to this article, worried that the Chinese government might not be pleased with the WTA's statement. So, he's worried that releasing this statement "could jeopardise the tour’s future in China", speaking about the WTA tour.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster *tour*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tour)
noun
b : a series of professional tournaments (as in golf or tennis)

[American Heritage Dictionary *tour*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tour)

noun
7. Sports A series of professional tournaments, as in golf.